# Strange behaviour for online PDF's in Blackberry browsers(in the abscense of any PDF viewer)

Tags: blackberry, adobe, ghostscript

Currently I am working on two sites which hosts various documents in PDF formats. While testing the sites, I observed that, PDF's on one site are not opening in some blackberry models(Bold 9650,9700 and 9780). It gave an error ""application/pdf" not supported. However it worked perfectly on the other site, that too in the absence of any PDF viewer . PDF producers are different for both the sites. For one, its "GPL Ghostscript 9.04" and for other its "Adobe PDF Library 9.9". Is this creating an issue.Has anyone ever encountered such type of an issue before ?

Comment: I have not come across this before but again I have always used the Adobe Library. Create a pdf of the same document through the 2 different pdf creators and copy the pdf's over to device to see if the problem persists.